Running scripts when navigating between pages with Link component in Next.js 14
I am using Next.js 14 in my project and for navigation between pages, I am using the Link component. The problem is that my scripts do not execute when navigating between pages using Link, but they do run correctly when the page is refreshed.
When I use an a tag instead of the Link component and navigate between pages, everything works fine and the scripts execute. However, I want to use the Link component from Next.js and have the scripts execute when navigating between pages.
Is there a way to solve this issue? I would appreciate any guidance.
Versions:

Next.js: 14
Directory: app

Thank you.
I tried using the Link component from Next.js for navigation between pages, expecting my scripts to execute as they do when the page is refreshed. However, the scripts did not run when navigating with Link. To troubleshoot, I replaced the Link component with an a tag, and the scripts executed correctly. I expected the Link component to handle script execution in the same way as the a tag.

Can you show some example code ? how are the scripts invoked ?
